# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in DBeaver -- when opening sqlite database as a file

Tags: java, sqlite, dbeaver

First I was using the portable version of dbeaver. Then, I decided to install it.
(both are community edition)
In both cases I edited the dbeaver.ini file (multiple times) incrementally increasing memory to see if anything would work. Finally I tried setting this: -Xmx100000m  (~100GB of RAM!) and it still wouldn't open without the error. I have 32GB RAM installed and I did initially keep the setting under my actual max RAM, but then I thought, "What the heck? Let it cache to the SSD." But it still didn't work!

The sqlite database is only a little over 2GB. A little big but surely not unusual for a database.

Admittedly, this is just about my first time using dbeaver and sqlite so it's probably user error.